Why do some supervisors get angry at the idea of PhD students going to the industry?
I'm doing a PhD in physics in Europe, and planning to go to the industry after that. All the former PhD students that graduated from my group have gone to the industry, and all the current PhD students are planning to do the same. The main reason for this is that we can get jobs where we have to work half, earn double, get more respected and appreciated than during our PhD. Also, many want to stay with partner/spouses and start a family.
My problem is that I will have to tell my supervisor at some point of my decision. They really do not accept that we all want to go to the industry, and they get really angry and disappointed about it. Last time we spoke, they told me they don't understand why people don't want simply to move to the other side of the planet to pursue a postdoc, instead they want to have roots here, together with their families. Why do I care? Because I want to finish the PhD as soon as possible (I hope to submit my thesis soon), and I don't want any unnecessary trouble for my graduation.
To prepare myself for this discussion, I would like to try to see things from their perspective, to understand why they have all this anger about it, which is unreasonable to me. So I am asking to you, why should a professor care about the life choices of their students? Do they get more funding if their former students become postdocs? Is it about prestige? Are we ruining their CV by going to the industry? Are they getting mobbed by the other professors, if they can't present an army of successful postdocs? Are they losing possibility of coauthorships on papers? Do they feel failures as supervisors? Are they worried that we might be happier and richer than them?
My supervisor has always been absent during my research, so it can't be that I have been a waste of time for them.
In my subfield I have seen that many seniors have the following attitude: we are very lucky people, because we're paid to do something that is a hobby to us, so we are not working one day of our life. This is not a job, rather a mission to expand the horizon of humankind's knowledge. This unfortunately translates, for us students, that everything else is seen as a distraction: family, friends, hobbies, free time and stuff should be avoided to focus 24/7 on our research. Also, we are all expected to strongly desire to become professors. So, could this anger come from some sort of sense of betrayal to these community values? Is it a sort of fanaticism?
I would like to approach this discussion in a professional and mature way, and understanding their feelings could help me in phrasing things in the best possible way, without blaming them for anything.

"All the former PhD students that graduated from my group have gone to the industry, and all the current PhD students are planning to do the same." Just to be clear: This really isn’t hyperbole and not a single student of theirs ever has continued in science?

You might be interested: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/108543/what-makes-academic-failure-different-from-failure-in-another-career

You seem to be extrapolating from a sample of one. We don't know the person. They are what they are.

@MisterMiyagi: no, this is not an hyperbole, I really mean that. Out of curiosity, I have counted all the past and current students, and we are 18 people in total.
Some of them might have thought about staying in science at the beginning of their PhD, but they all changed their mind during their PhD.

@Buffy: I actually know around 10-15 professors in my subfield that think like my supervisor. The difference here is that I don't have to daily deal with them, I don't depend on them for graduation, so I don't care. I stopped going to conferences to avoid meeting them. However, if they exist, this phenomenon might be unfortunately more common than we think.

I would guess that it is a combination of most of those, except the one about being "mobbed" which I can't understand. Also they might feel disappointed in you because you seem to care about money too much, as they see it. Perhaps they have adequate salaries, and regard it as distasteful to want a high salary so much that you would abandon academia for it.

As a tangential remark, given all that I've read the past few years about colleges and universities (at least in the U.S.) downsizing and even closing degree programs (both undergraduate and graduate) in order to shift increasingly smaller resources to degree programs that are perceived as having greater employment options for their graduates, a professor in a situation where his/her students have obtained reasonably lucrative jobs in their field of study would likely be viewed very positively by the college/university administration.

A professor might regard academia as having higher status than industry; if all his students go into industry, they could drag his status down. Another possibility is that a professor wants to have people following in his footsteps; his students would be the obvious candidates for that.

@BlackPhoenix Okay, if every single one of my students would show me they consider my line of work not worthwhile, I would be pretty unhappy too. Whether this applies to your supervisor depends on them, of course.

I usually tell students that if none (or extremely few) of the PhD students of a given professor stay in the field (not necessarily forever, but maybe for an initial postdoc) to consider that a red flag when picking a PhD advisor. (Note that I am in the UK, a PhD plus initial postdoc takes about the same time as a USA based PhD.)

This question was closed by supervisors who get angry at the idea of PhD students going to the industry. [comment removed]
